# MINLP Optimization using Pyomo not maximizing the outcome

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am working on a optimization problem with two decision variables X and Y.

X is a binary variable that should tell me if I need to make a product or not ( I have 10 products). Variable Y is the optimized hours I can produce within the max hours per product constraint .

**Objective Function**

I am trying to maximize the sum product of binary decision variable X  and the production "urgency" of that product so that the model picks the most urgent products and produce as much as we can.

**Constraints:**

I can only spend a maximum of 35 hours producing these items ie. the sum of all the hours for all products should be less than or equal to 35. I cannot use the equality constraint here since I may encounter the sum of 'max hours' less than 35 in the future.

It is also better if we can complete more of one product compared to producing little bit of everything ( constraint not included here).

Also, I do not want to produce more than the required hours ('max hours' ) for individual products.

**Issue**

What I want to see the total hours close or equal to the max hours(35) by selecting the most urgent products and producing as much as I can. However, the model is not doing that.  I am not sure if my formulation is correct. It is possible to provide some advice?

Thanks

```
code



# import pyomo.environ as pyo

from pyomo.environ import *

from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory



line=[3]

product=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]





data={3: {1: {'urgency': 0.0, 'max_hours': 0},

  2: {'urgency': 0.0, 'max_hours': 0},

  3: {'urgency': 0.36, 'max_hours': 5},

  4: {'urgency': 0.23, 'max_hours': 2},

  5: {'urgency': 0.32, 'max_hours': 6},

  6: {'urgency': 0.67, 'max_hours': 10},

  7: {'urgency': 10, 'max_hours': 22},

  8: {'urgency': 0.73, 'max_hours': 4},

  9: {'urgency': 0.81, 'max_hours': 3},

  10: {'urgency': 0.43,  'max_hours': 4}}}



model = pyo.ConcreteModel()



model.x = pyo.Var(line,product, domain=pyo.Binary)

model.y = pyo.Var(line,product, within=Integers, bounds=(0,None))



model.cost = pyo.Objective(expr = sum([model.x[l,p]*data[l][p]['urgency'] for l in [3] for p in product]),sense=maximize)



model.c3 = pyo.Constraint(expr =sum(model.x[l,p]*model.y[l,p] for l in [3] for p in product)<=35)



model.constraint_prod = pyo.ConstraintList()

for l in [3]:

    for p in product:

        model.constraint_prod.add(expr=data[l][p]['max_hours']>=model.x[l,p]*model.y[l,p])

        

        

solver = SolverFactory('bonmin', executable='/libraries/Default_env_39400/bin/bonmin')

solver.solve(model)

model.pprint()
```

Comment: before we fix the formulation, it appears there is some missing info here.  Can you explain what `y` is again and include an example?  It seems the "hours required to make product x" is missing.  If the model was working, why wouldn't it product 0.1 hrs on every product and maximize the sum of `x`?  Or even 0 hrs on every product as there doesn't seem to be a requirement to make one, just a max.

Comment: And OBTW, the main issue here aside from the questionable formulation is the multiplication of variables in constraint 3, which makes the problem non-linear.  This can be avoided.